# Error occuring while getting the recorded voice stored in the external storage to view in a listview?

Tags: java, android

Error occurring while i recorded the voice calls and stored in the external storage and i need to view the stored voice calls datas in listview in my activity.
I attached the code below.
Error occurring at line

```
files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name);
       File list[] = files.listFiles();
```

In below program.

Kindly Please help me to solve this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button btn;
   ListView listView;    MediaPlayer mp;
   private static final String files = null;
   ArrayList myList;
   ArrayAdapter adapter;
   Context context;    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
       mp = new MediaPlayer();
       // this will show the recorded files into ListVIew
       myList = new ArrayList<String>();
       files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name);
       File list[] = files.listFiles();
       for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
           myList.add(list[i].getName());
       }        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {                try {
                   playSong(files + myList.get(position));
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.d("PlaySong", "Error in Playing song "+e.toString());
               }                // just for checking the position of item in list
               Object listItem = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + listItem,
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }            private void playSong(String string) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException {                mp.reset();
               mp.setDataSource(string);
               mp.prepare();
               mp.start();
           }        });
   }
}


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;/**
* Created by seyali-01 on 6/11/16.
*/public class CallRecordReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   Intent intent;
   File f1;
   MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;    @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.v("Action ", "Phone" + intent.getAction());        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + context.getString(R.string.app_name);
       File dir = new File(path);
       if (!dir.exists()) {
           dir.mkdir();
       }        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
           // Phone is ringing
           Log.v("Action ", "Phone is Ringing");        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
           // Call received
           Log.v("Action ", "Phone is received");
           try {
               f1 = File.createTempFile("Sound", ".3gp", dir);
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
           mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
           mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
           mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
           mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(f1.getAbsolutePath());
           try {
               mediaRecorder.prepare();
           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           mediaRecorder.start();        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {            // Call Dropped or rejected
           Log.v("Action ", "Phone is Rejected");        }
   }}enter code here`enter code here`
```

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: which error occures exactly? and where is a stacktrace?

Comment: the error occurring at  File list[] = files.listFiles();

Comment: the error was Cannot solve the listFiles();   This type of error occurring